# Extra horizontal width on responsive site when viewed at small resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a responsive site with Twitter Bootstrap, however when I view the site in a screen resolution of 320x480 a horizontal scroll bar appears as the website seems to have an extra 20px-30px width. You can see this by scrolling too the right horizontally.

I have inspected the elements that form the page, however I can not work out what is causing this extra width - ideally I do not want any horizontal scrolling at the 320x480 resolution.

You can view the problem by changing the resolution to 320x480 in Google Chrome after inspecting an element.

Here is the site:

http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/wp/

Comment: Have you tried `overflow-x: hidden;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enabled the Bootstrap's responsive features?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please note that bootstrap-responsive.css must be included and referenced on your website

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I have enabled the responsive features.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `.jumbotron` and `.footer` css rule `margin-right: -20px;` causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try resetting lateral margins from -20px to 0 for header and footer tags

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.footer{
     width: 85%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     /* other css properties */
}
```